# Can a use-case use the same classes which already used by other use-case?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, use-case

Let's take the example of using the same DB wrapper for different use-cases.
Does it make sense to use different use-cases (or class diagrams), which use the same DB wrapper?
Or it's necessary to merge the use-cases into one?

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand your question. What has an implementation (DB wrapper) got to do with a use case?

Comment: ditto...could you elaborate please?